# jQuery: method doesn't load?

Tags: visualforce, jquery

Anyone have any experience diagnosing jQuery methods in SF?

This seems to me like it should work fine:

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" />
<script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    function loadText() {
        var self = j$(this),
            src  = this.value,
            box  = j$('input[id$=textBody]');

        console.log(src);

        (src) ? box.val() = src : box.val() = '';
    }

    j$('select[id$=textSelectList]').change(loadText).trigger('change');
</script>
```

I get no console output from the logging in that method. The HTML/VF all matches up:

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:selectList id="textSelectList" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!textTemplates}" />
    </apex:selectList>
    <apex:inputTextarea value="{!textBody}" id="textBody" />
    <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!sendText}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Any ideas?

[image: errors]

**Update**

Full page here:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="TextLeadController">
    <head>
        <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" />
        <script>
            var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

            function loadText() {
                var self = j$(this),
                    src  = this.value,
                    box  = j$('input[id$=textBody]');

                console.log(src);

                (src) ? box.val() = src : box.val() = '';
            }

            j$('select[id$=textSelectList]').change(loadText).trigger('change');
        </script>
    </head>

    <div class="bPageTitle">
        <div class="ptBody">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="/s.gif" alt="Lead" class="pageTitleIcon" title="Lead" />
                <h1 class="pageType">Lead<span class="titleSeparatingColon"></span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <apex:form >
                    <apex:selectRadio value="{!number}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!phoneNumbers}" />
                    </apex:selectRadio>
                    <apex:selectList id="textSelectList" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!textTemplates}" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                    <br /><br />
                    <apex:inputTextarea value="{!textBody}" id="textBody" style="width: 400px; height: 150px;" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!sendText}"/>
                </apex:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you putting the script before or after the VF markup?  If the script is before then it will run before your content has rendered.

Comment: Could you add a bit more of your page? I added your code to one of my pages and it loaded fine.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution, for anyone else stuck. Order matters, and, of course, calling a `textarea` `input` in the jQuery does no one any favours.

```
<div class="bPageTitle">
    <div class="ptBody">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="/s.gif" alt="Lead" class="pageTitleIcon" title="Lead" />
            <h1 class="pageType">Lead<span class="titleSeparatingColon"></span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <apex:form>
                <apex:selectList id="textSelectList" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!textTemplates}" />
                </apex:selectList>
                <br /><br />
                <apex:inputTextarea value="{!textBody}" id="textBody" style="width: 400px; height: 150px;" />
                <br /><br />
                <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!sendText}"/>
            </apex:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    function loadText() {
        var self = j$(this),
            src = this.value,
            area = j$('textarea[id$=textBody]');

        console.log(src);
        area.val(src);
    }

    j$('select[id$=textSelectList]').change(loadText).trigger('change');
</script>
```

Comment: If you use `j$(document).ready(function() { ...}`, the jQuery doesn't execute until after the page loads. see https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Apps_with_jQuery. In my experience, this avoids the order dependency issue

Answer (score 1):

If you use `j$(document).ready(function() { ...}`, the jQuery within the closure doesn't execute until after the page loads.

Or, using jQuery shorthand: `j$(function() {..}`

That is ..

```
<script>
  var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
  j$(function() {..}  // your jQuery that needs to execute after page load
  // other functions and jQuery that is not page load dependent
</script>
```

See the [blog post by Developer Evangelist Josh Birk.](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-jquery-in-a-visualforce-page) Also see this [VF and jQuery blog post by Josh Birk.](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Apps_with_jQuery) In my experience, this avoids the order dependency issue.